# cron não atualiza banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Criei um arquivo php para verificar se tem algum usuário vencido o atualizar o status dele com atualização do banco de dados 1 vez ao dia. Estou agendando a cron pelo CPANEL da hostgator.
Se eu executar o arquivo no navegador ele faz o processo corretamente, porem pela cron ele sempre pula a consulta mysql indo direto par a mensagem (**Nenhum cliente para atualizar status**) mesmo tendo.

**Código PHP**

```
$hoje       = Date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$menos30    = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$a_vencer   = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+10 days'));
$vencido    = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'));

$consulta = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status IN (6, 7, 8)");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

if ($linhas > 0) {
    while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {

        $id             = $dados['id'];
        $name_user      = $dados['first_name'];
        $due_date       = $dados['due_date'];
        $status_user    = $dados['status'];

        if ($vencimento == $a_vencer) {

            $atualiza = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE customers SET status = 11, change_date = '$hoje' WHERE codigo = '$id_user'");
            if ($atualiza) {
                echo "Atualizado o status do usuário a vencer em 10 dias: $id - $name_user - VENCE EM -> " . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($vencimento)) . "<br>";
            } else {
                echo "Erro ao atualizar vencimento em 10 dias do usuário  - $id - $name_user - EM -> " . date('d/m/Y h:i:s') . "<br>";
            }
        } elseif ($vencimento < $vencido) {

            $atualiza = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE customers SET status = 9, change_date = '$hoje' WHERE codigo = '$id_user'");
            if ($atualiza) {
                echo "Atualizado o status do cliente vencido: $id - $name_user - VENCEU EM -> " . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($vencimento)) . "<br>";
            } else {
                echo "Erro ao atualizar o cliente vencido - $id - $name_user - EM -> " . date('d/m/Y h:i:s') . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum cliente para atualizar status - " . date('d/m/y h:i:s') . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Se está caindo no `else` é porque a condição `if ($linhas > 0)` não é satisfeita. Tem certeza que está conectando no banco de dados correto e que não está dando erro na consulta?

Comment: Sim, pois quando executo direto no navegador ele efetuar a atualização. Mais acredito que seja a configuração da cron, estou vendo na documentação para ver como executar arquivo php corretamente na cron da hostgator

Comment: E você tem certeza que quando a CRON é executada há registros pendentes para atualização?

Comment: Sim existe, porque quando dou um select na base, o mesmo select que uso no arquivo, ele tem o retorno, mais consegui resolver com um configuração na chamada da cron, foi necessário colocar php -q antes da chamada da cron. De qualquer forma obrigado